# How to match enclosing brackets which are next to each other?

Tags: regex, go

I'm am attempting to parse lines of Helm templates. I run into issues when I have value declarations side-by-side on the same line.

For example, the line `image: "{{ $.Values.image.repository }}:{{ $.Values.image.tag }}"` returns one big match as opposed to two matches within the brackets.

I have tried using `(\-)?( )?(.*):( )\{\{( )(\$)?.Values.*\}\}`.

I'd like to get both value instances instead of one large instance.

Comment: Are you escaping `.`? As per the [syntax spec](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), `.` matches any character, so your `.*` at the end will match all following characters, including `}`s.

Comment: This is probably better served by a discrete parser than a regexp (and I'm saying that as someone very fond of regexp where it's appropriate).

Comment: Parsing text is very common and pretty straightforward. For something like this you'd probably just want to loop over the string character by character and apply your logic to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe you might want to write an expression that'd look somewhat similar to:

```
\s*{{\s*\$?\.Values([^}]*)?\s*}}
```

#### Test

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)\s*{{\s*\$?\.Values([^}]*)?\s*}}`)
    var str = `image: "{{ $.Values.image.repository }}:{{ $.Values.image.tag }}`

    for i, match := range re.FindAllString(str, -1) {
        fmt.Println(match, "found at index", i)
    }
}
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0xMQiq/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/0xMQiq/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this won't match anything with a single `}` inside the double-braces. I don't know if that's a problem in practice.